# Could not find vstest test logger with URI or FriendlyName

Tags: c#, vstest

I'm trying to implement my custom `vstest` logger by following this article [Writing loggers for command line test runner vstest.console.exe](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vikramagrawal/2012/07/26/writing-loggers-for-command-line-test-runner-vstest-console-exe/?replytocom=133#respond) I have 3 projects inside VS solution.

**ClassLibrary1**
Contains only one sample `Service` class.

```
public class Service
    {
        public int GetDocumentNumber(Guid documentId)
        {
            if (documentId == Guid.Empty)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Document id is empty guid.");
            }

            return 178;
        }
    }
```

**SimpleLoggerVSTest** (ClassLibrary)
Contains only one class. The `ITestLogger` is an interface from `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel`.

```
[ExtensionUri("logger://SimpleConsoleLogger/v1")] /// Uri used to uniquely identify the console logger. 
[FriendlyName("SimpleLogger")] /// Alternate user friendly string to uniquely identify the logger.
        public class SimpleLogger : ITestLogger
        {
            public void Initialize(TestLoggerEvents events, string testRunDirectory)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("++++ Initialize ++++");
            }
        }
```

**UnitTestProject**
Contains only one test class.

```
[TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            // Arrange 
            Guid documentId = Guid.NewGuid();
            Service service = new Service();

            // Act
            var res = service.GetDocumentNumber(documentId);

            // Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(res, 178);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod2()
        {
            // Arrange 
            Guid documentId = Guid.Empty;
            Service service = new Service();

            // Act
            var res = service.GetDocumentNumber(documentId);

            // Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(res, 178);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
        public void TestMethod3()
        {
            // Arrange 
            Guid documentId = Guid.Empty;
            Service service = new Service();

            // Act
            service.GetDocumentNumber(documentId);
        }
    }
```

The `UnitTestProject` has references to the first `ClassLibrary` and the `SimpleLoggerVSTest`.

I tired to execute the following command into `Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017`.

```
cd C:\Users\User\source\repos\Solution2\UnitTestProject1\bin\Debug
vstest.console.exe UnitTestProject1.dll /TestAdapterPath:. /Logger:SimpleLogger
```

I got the following error:

> Could not find a test logger with URI or FriendlyName 'SimpleLogger'.

What I did wrong? Could you help me?

**EDIT:** So, I have heard that it may be caused by old version of Visual Studio. But I have 15.6.3.

Comment: @haim770 I commented `ExtensionUri` attribute and used lowercase command. It didn't help. I got the same error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure your SimpleLogger class present in assembly whose name ends with testlogger.dll.

Comment: What's the logic behind? Am i right that i should call my dll `something_testlogger.dll`? Or your answer is about something else (which's not quite clear to me)? Thanks!

Comment: vstest.console.exe looks for `ITestLogger` implementations only in assemblies which ends with testlogger.dll. Yes, it should be somethig_testlogger.dll.